# Is it true that when passing an argument to a function, it is like assigning the value to the parameter?

Tags: c++, parameter-passing, function-parameter

I am new to C++ and I am writing pseudo code here:

```
void fn(a) {}
fn(b)
```

It is correct to assume that in the function body `fn` what happens is this assignment

```
`a = b`
```

I know we can pass the reference/pointer instead of just the value. I get it. But at its core, it still does this assignment of `parameter = argument` right?

I would like to know:

1. if there is any official term for this?
2. when exactly does this assignment happen and what exactly makes this happen? is it the compiler?

Comment: More or less. Not exactly assignment, more like initialization. (1) For what? Does "passing an argument" sound official? (2) Of course it's the compiler, what else could it be? It happens before the function is called?

Comment: Without minimally *valid* and *compiling* code, it's not really "correct" to assume anything. Perhaps you're looking for the terms ["call by value" and "call by reference"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#:~:text=Call%20by%20reference%20(or%20pass,a%20copy%20of%20its%20value.)). Call by reference does not exist in C; hence why the dual tags (coupled with the invalid/incomplete code) are especially problematic here.

Comment: Do not tag both C and C++ except when asking about differences or interactions between the two languages. Answers may be different in the different languages.

Comment: hey thanks for the suggestion. I took down the `c` tag.

Comment: @Joji Still need some compiling code. Consider these two different functions, substituting in a value for "a", and how such might affect answers and/or what is being sought: `void f(int x) { x = 2; }` and `void g(int& x) { x = 2; }`.

Comment: according to cppreference.com, the thing used is "implicit conversion". "Assignment" could be imprecise/incorrect: I don't know, if there's a scenario where this would be different to an assignment initializing a variable, at least, if mandatory copy elision (C++17) happens. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_function_call_operator Btw: "the order of the assignments" can be arbitrary for multiple params

Answer (score 3):

> if there is any official term for this?

The official semantics of a function call are discussed in the “Function call” section of the C standard. There is no term specifically for the assignments of values to parameters.

C++ 2017 draft N4659 8.2.2 “Function call” [expr.call] 4 says:

> When a function is called, each parameter (11.3.5) shall be initialized (11.6, 15.8, 15.1) with its corresponding argument…

> when exactly does this assignment happen and what exactly makes this happen? is it the compiler?

It happens when a function is called. The compiler is responsible for generating code that produces a program that performs the semantics of the source code (as defined by the C++ standard).

Comment: can I ask what the differences  are between the "being initialized" and an assignment like `int a = b`?

Comment: @Joji: `int a = b` is an initialization. `a = b` is an assignment. I will leave it to C++ experts to discuss any difference or similarity between initialization and assignment.

Comment: Initialisation is the action (or set of actions) that give a object a value as it is created.   Assignment is the action of changing the value of an object.   For struct/class types, initialisation involves calling a constructor and assignment involves calling a member function named `operator=()`.

Comment: I see.. it seems like initialization is basically just the first assignment.

Answer (score 2):

The C++ standard describes an execution environment, the results of various types of statements and the results of various types of expressions. A compiler is only required to produce code that, when,run, produces results as-if it were run on that described execution environment.

In terms of your actual question, that means that a function call in source code does not necessarily translate into any sort of call or jump instruction when run on actual hardware.

For example, given the function:

```
int sqr(int x, inty)
{
  return x*y;
}
```

a compiler might well simply compute such a result in-place and not perform any sort of parameter passing. But whether you can actually count on that behavior is a detail left up to the compiler implementor.

All that being said, on actual hardware and without inlining, a function call's parameters are very much like any other variable initialization (think copy rather than assign). The exact details (such as order of parameter evaluation) are left up to each implementation.

Comment: hey thanks for the reply! If it is just variable initialization, how does it get its value without an assignment?